# symmetric AES encryption with php produces different result than openssl MacOX

Tags: aes, openssl

I need to make a simple very basic encryption with AES 128 ECB mode.

The idea is to generate a cryptogram, code it in base64 and then decipher that text from a web service in php to process its content. Later we will increase the robustness of the encryption with a 256 key and CBC mode.

The problem is that the encrypted text generated from the openssl tool (installed by default in MacOX) generates a completely different result than the one generated by the openssl_encrypt function in php 7.

```
echo -n 'Sergio Sánchez' | openssl12n enc -aes-128-ecb  -a
```

Result

```
U2FsdGVkX1+wrLjaCTSM9T3WMV1YcD9Cwzj0mKBoa7M=
```

No Salt

```
echo -n 'Sergio Sánchez' | openssl12n enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -a
```

Result

```
stpJKCaUQ/Q1GLzDvqaYRg==
```

PHP 7

```
echo base64_encode(openssl_encrypt('Sergio Sánchez', 'AES-128-ECB', 'password', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
```

Result

```
dum7MBJOzIi9jvMTvEYnug==
```

How can I generate a compatible cryptogram between both tools?

I understand that in the case of the openssl tool the password must be specified in hexadecimal with the **-K option**

```
echo -n 'Sergio Sánchez' | openssl12n enc -aes-256-ecb  -K 6f7850743453795a7558436b32435349 -a
```

The generated result will be the following:

```
F7O/3OIi120ReItAJIk0oQ==
```

In the case of php I specify the key in text:

```
echo openssl_encrypt('Sergio Sánchez', 'AES-128-ECB', 'oxPt4SyZuXCk2CSI');
```

The generated result will be the following

```
dum7MBJOzIi9jvMTvEYnug==
```

Comment: This question has an accepted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198243/451475).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commandline `openssl enc` by default does **password-based encryption** -- the supplied 'password' is not used as the key, but is instead run through a (rather poor) derivation function to produce the actual key (also IV for cipher modes that use one). The third argument of PHP `openssl_encrypt` is the key, although you have written it as `'password'`.

You can give `enc` the actual key instead of a password by using `-K` (uppercase, not `-k`) with the key in hex. When using this option you also need to provide the IV explicitly with `-iv` and hex if the cipher mode requires it, but ECB doesn't. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#104438 .

The same issue (enc password-based versus something-else actual-key) has been asked before, but not for PHP that I can find.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354200/blowfish-encrypt-in-java-scala-and-decrypt-in-bash
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855972/different-results-when-encrypting-with-openssl
[Discrepancy between 3DES in OpenSSL and PyDES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/discrepancy-between-3des-in-openssl-and-pydes)

PS: if you *don't* set OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, openssl_encrypt does base64 for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I have tried the solution you mention with the password in hexadecimal. It generates another different result. I have edited the question with the results

Comment: You changed the openssl to -K but also to aes-256-ecb which is not the same as aes-128-ecb. With aes-128-ecb I get the same result as PHP.